# Angular Best Practice: Passing data as input or using query params

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am designing an application, and confused with would be a better practice. I want to make http requests based on the inputs that I get from other component. So, I have 2 different ways to send data from one component to the component that makes the API call (through a service).

- Using @Input()
- by extracting the query params from the url ( as I want to persist the input data in the url)

I am not sure if get the data using Router service's parseUrl method in the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook (`this._router.parseUrl(this._router.url).queryParams.fund1`) or simply using ngOnChanges with the following check

```
if (changes['fund1'] &&
    changes['fund1'].currentValue &&
    changes['fund1'].previousValue !== changes['portIdFund1'].currentValue
  )
```

Is it good to inject Router service into the component or just leverage the Angular native @Input? I have to write more code with the later (@Input).

Answer (score 0):

*Is it good to inject Router service into the component?*

Yes, This is how/why services is used for.

Do not over complicate your components by including too many inputs which you can easily get from services.

but this does not mean that you can use services recklessly. You need to keep balance.